# Можно ли оптимизировать данный запрос или смотреть в сторону денормализации?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация-запросов

Данный SQL запрос имеет различные модификации в коде, но суть одна - он работает на вывод объявлений, с информацией о категории и региональности.

Для наглядности покажу изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам запрос. В нем нет ничего сложного, это JOIN на несколько таблиц и условия в WHERE:

```
explain SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *
    FROM `advert`
    INNER JOIN `user-country` ON `advert`.`advert_place_country` = `user-country`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `user-region` ON `advert`.`advert_place_region` = `user-region`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `user-city` ON `advert`.`advert_place_city` = `user-city`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `advert`.`advert_id_user`
    INNER JOIN `category` ON `advert`.`advert_category` = `category`.`id`
    WHERE
        `advert_active` = 1 
        AND `advert`.`advert_payment` = 1 
        AND `advert_place_country` = 3159 
        AND `user`.`user_active` = 1
    ORDER BY
        `advert`.`advert_create_date`
    DESC
LIMIT 0, 80
```

Вот explain:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня не устраивает время обработки запроса в 0.3 секунды и кол-во затрагиваемых строк. Индекс такой:

```
`findListForCatalog` (
    `advert_active`,
    `advert_payment`,
    `advert_place_country`,
    `advert_place_region`, // в данном запросе не используется 
    `advert_place_city`    // в данном запросе не используется
),
```

Я сейчас не могу понять, что делать - либо думать о денормализации данных и создавать триггеры, который будут информацию региональности и категории писать в таблицу объявлений adverts, либо я что-то не так делаю?

В таблице всего 20 000 записей, но время работы в 0.3 меня совсем не устраивает.

Comment: Если убрать все join, из самой таблицы advert выборка с таким же where и order by сколько занимает времени ? Склоняюсь к тому, что бы сделать такой запрос, обернуть его во from внешнего запроса и уже к нему выполнять join остальных таблиц. но в итоге запроса может понадобится еще один order by и это нормально

Comment: А стоп, лимит то применить не получиться. там у вас еще user.is_active затесалось :( Значит user надо клеить то же сразу.

Comment: И еще интересно почему он в плане пишет 18к строк, неужели первые 3 условия where действительно отбирают около 18 из 20 тыс строк ?

Comment: Времени будет меньше - 0.0003

Comment: А первый 3 условия во where действительно отбирают почти все записи - это активные, не закрытые объявления из страны РФ.

Comment: В сортировке `advert_create_date`, а индекса нет по нему.

Comment: view еще никто не предлагал сделать?

Comment: view чем поможет и как сделать?

Comment: грубо говоря view - это предварительная таблица из результатов какого-то запроса. Она хранится в базе и в любой момент времени представляет результат заданного запроса. Можете сделать даже денормализованное представление своих данных. и в конечных запросах опрашивать не кучу исходных таблиц, а небольшое количество вьюх. Вы можете даже сделать view из своего запроса `create view my_view ... as ...`, а в программе написать `select * from my_view`

Comment: @gr-oborona-adverts Но насчёт шустрости view я ничего сказать не могу. У Вас точно субд тормозит, а не клиент?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю попробовать следующий вариант:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT advert.*, user.... (нужные поля из user)
      FROM `advert`
     INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `advert`.`advert_id_user`
     WHERE `advert_active` = 1 
       AND `advert`.`advert_payment` = 1 
       AND `advert_place_country` = 3159 
       AND `user`.`user_active` = 1
     ORDER BY `advert`.`advert_create_date` DESC
     LIMIT 0, 80
  ) advert
 INNER JOIN `user-country` ON `advert`.`advert_place_country` = `user-country`.`id`
 INNER JOIN `user-region` ON `advert`.`advert_place_region` = `user-region`.`id`
 INNER JOIN `user-city` ON `advert`.`advert_place_city` = `user-city`.`id`
 INNER JOIN `category` ON `advert`.`advert_category` = `category`.`id`
 ORDER BY `advert`.`advert_create_date` DESC
```

Чтобы связи через `JOIN` большинства таблиц были уже только с теми 80 записями, которые нужны, а не со всей выборкой до `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все джойны это связи один к одному. То есть вы выбираете рекламные объявления и джойны нужны только для того чтобы выбрать данные по айдишкам. Кроме пользователя. Для него есть условие, что он активный.

Если идти по объявлениям страны РФ, отсортированным по дате добавления, то можно было бы выбрать только 80 строк. Если бы у бд был составной индекс (advert_place_country, advert_create_date), то она бы могла использовать его.

Кстати, обратите внимание, что индексы по булевым полям обычно мало эффективны. Кажется нет смысла в индексе по advert_active и advert_payment. Можно приделать их к составным индексам для каких-нибудь запросов, но по отдельности они ничего не дают.

UPD:

Экспериментируя, обнаружил, что mysql не умет оптимизировать (возможно только в моём случае) сортировку при джойнах. Он пытается сперва сджойнить и только потом применить сортировку к результату объединения.

В этом случае подзапрос оказывается гораздо шустрее.

```
select *
from `advert`
where
    `advert_active` = 1 
    and `advert_payment` = 1 
    and `advert_place_country` = 1
    and (select `user`.`active` from `user` where `user`.`id` = `advert`.`advert_id_user`) = true
order by `advert_create_date` desc
limit 0, 80
```

Таким образом можно получить id нужных записей и сделать второй запрос на получение данных уже с джойнами (или использовать решение Майка).

Comment: Насчет индексов по булевым полям учту, спасибо. А вот с остальным я не понял. Составной индекс на  (advert_place_country, advert_create_date)? Результат такой же по строкам..

Comment: @gr-oborona-adverts булевы поля у вас часть составного индекса, я не заметил сразу. Количество строк в explain тут не главный показатель производительности. Раньше вы выбирали все объявления и запускали сортировку, потом отбрасывали большую часть данных. С индексом строки уже отсортированы и не надо выбирать их все. Что со скоростью выполнения запроса? Я накидал синтетический тест и 0.001 против 0.05 (100k записей)